# PivotItem header disappears when set to a custom UserControl

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create closeable pivot headers in UWP, so that "close" boxes with X's in them are displayed, like so:

[image: closeable tab headers]

As you might have guessed, I have the simplest case working. But when I tried rolling it into my "real" app, the headers don't display. They're there, and if I click up at the top left of the Pivot, the PivotItems change, but there's no visible header (and the "touch active" area where I can click to change items is very small).

To make this close to the simplest case, here's what I'm doing when I select a "Test" AppBarButton:

```
// Header disappears from PivotItem!
PivotItem piTemp = ((PivotItem)this.pvtFiles.Items[0]);
CloseableTabHeader cth = new CloseableTabHeader("This is jive", piTemp, this.pvtFiles);
piTemp.Header = cth;
```

Here's the XAML from the CloseableTabHeader:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CloseableTabs.CloseableTabHeader"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CloseableTabs"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="txtHeader" FontSize="18">Test</TextBlock>
        <Button Background="White" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <PathIcon Data="M13.3000001907349,2.09999990463257L3.5,2.09999990463257 2.51005053520203,2.51005053520203 2.09999990463257,3.5 2.09999990463257,13.3000001907349 2.51005053520203,14.2899494171143 3.5,14.6999998092651 13.3000001907349,14.6999998092651 14.2899494171143,14.2899494171143 14.6999998092651,13.3000001907349 14.6999998092651,3.5 14.2899494171143,2.51005053520203 13.3000001907349,2.09999990463257 M13.3000001907349,13.3000001907349L3.5,13.3000001907349 3.5,3.5 13.3000001907349,3.5 13.3000001907349,13.3000001907349 M11.8999996185303,5.87999963760376L9.3799991607666,8.39999961853027 11.8999996185303,10.9200000762939 10.9200000762939,11.8999996185303 8.39999961853027,9.3799991607666 5.87999963760376,11.8999996185303 4.90000009536743,10.9200000762939 7.42000007629395,8.39999961853027 4.90000009536743,5.87999963760376 5.87999963760376,4.90000009536743 8.39999961853027,7.42000007629395 10.9200000762939,4.90000009536743 11.8999996185303,5.87999963760376z" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

... and here's the rest of the partial class...

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace CloseableTabs
{
    public sealed partial class CloseableTabHeader : UserControl
    {
        public PivotItem itemParent = null;
        public Pivot pivotParent = null;

        public CloseableTabHeader(string headerText,
            PivotItem itemParent, Pivot pivotParent) : base()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            txtHeader.Text = headerText;
            this.itemParent = itemParent;
            this.pivotParent = pivotParent;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != this.itemParent && null != this.pivotParent)
            {
                this.pivotParent.Items.Remove(this.itemParent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, in my simplest case project, that works great. Quick details from MainPage:

#### XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <Pivot Name="pvtMain">
        <PivotItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Content content content" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Content2 content2 content2" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Content3 content3 content3" />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
    <Button Content="spam" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

#### Constructor & Button Event Handler, Simplest Case

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.pvtMain.GetPIByIndex(0).Header = new CloseableTabHeader("Header Text", this.pvtMain.GetPIByIndex(0), this.pvtMain);
    this.pvtMain.GetPIByIndex(1).Header = "header 2";
    this.pvtMain.GetPIByIndex(2).Header = "header 3";
}

// WORKS!
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CloseableTabHeader cth = new CloseableTabHeader("Header2 Text", this.pvtMain.GetPIByIndex(1), this.pvtMain);
    this.pvtMain.GetPIByIndex(1).Header = cth;
}
```

GetPIByIndex is a convenience extension...

```
public static PivotItem GetPIByIndex(this Pivot pivot, int index)
{
    return (PivotItem)pivot.Items[index];
}
```

There really isn't a significant different between the two UIs other than the "real" app is more complex. But the Pivot is the first thing in the "real" app's Grid... The simplest case app obviously uses a StackPanel, but I don't any trouble getting the headers to display when they're simply text.

That is, in the "real" app, I'm currently loading with strings in my PivotItems' Headers, then handling an event from an AppBarButton with the swap to a CloseableTabHeader, just as I'm doing in the `Button_Click` event in the simplest case.

Any obvious gotchas here? Why would it work well in the simplest case, but not in the production app?

---

**EDIT:** Here's a diff of a dump of the two CloseableTabHeaders right before I push them into the respective PivotItem's Headers:

```
0a1
> cth
9,10c10,11
<     BaseUri: {ms-appx:///com/rufwork/mumd/UI/CloseableTabs.xaml}
---
>     BaseUri: {ms-appx:///CloseableTabHeader.xaml}
39c40
<     Height: 200
---
>     Height: NaN
85c86
<     Width: 200
---
>     Width: NaN
```

So there is something funky going on with size, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Because I'm an idiot.

I didn't like how big the text was in the `PivotItem`'s `Header`s in the production app, so apparently a forgettably long time ago, I'd forcefully changed the `Pivot.HeaderTemplate` in the production app's XAML.

```
<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- Here, I was just changing the FontSize to something more
             manageable/less gaudy -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Height="Auto" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

So naturally if I change what I'm throwing into the binding (I guess perhaps it was throwing my UserControl into Text?), blam.

**Remove that HeaderTemplate** and you're reasonably golden. Apologies that wasn't in the initial question, and I'll leave the question here, at least briefly, in case this is helpful to someone else.

Bottom line: If you've edited your Pivot at all for style, don't expect all other edits to be independent of those changes.